How can I move each polygon in a multipolygon file to a random new location within bbox?
I am trying to reassign the coordinates for every polygon in a multipolygon file, so that each would be placed in a random new location in a defined bounding box, while preserving its attributes. The polygons are based on landscape features, so they are not geometric.
This is what I did for a single polygon in R:
# Define bbox
bbox <- list(xmin=0, ymin=0, xmax=0, ymax=0)
bbox$x <- c(bbox$xmin, bbox$xmax)
bbox$y <- c(bbox$ymin, bbox$ymax)

# Read in polygon
pol <- st_read("polygon.shp")

# Generate random coordinates within the bounding box
random_x <- runif(1, min=bbox$xmin, max=bbox$xmax)
random_y <- runif(1, min=bbox$ymin, max=bbox$ymax)

# Calculate the centroid of the polygon
centroid <- st_centroid(pol)

# Calculate the difference between the random coordinates and the centroid
diff_x <- random_x - st_coordinates(centroid)[,1]
diff_y <- random_y - st_coordinates(centroid)[,2]

# Move the polygon to the new location
pol_shift <- st_geometry(pol) + c(diff_x, diff_y)
st_crs(pol_shift) = 4326 # re-assign CRS

I would like to do something similar as the above, but for multiple polygons - I'm not sure how to approach the iteration process.

Write a function that does whatever processing you want done on one polygon, then write a for-loop over all the polygons. Where are the other polygons? Are they all in separate shapefiles?
